# How to visualise the relationship between two variables based on another one in R?

Tags: r, variables, relationship

I have a table (based on a .csv file named "bikes"), which contains around 10,000 rows and looks like this:

```
rentals  season  weatherCondition
  12        1         4
  6         4         1
  21        1         4
  4         3         1
  5         3         2
  19        1         4
  13        1         3
  10        2         4
  8         2         3
  ..        ..        ..
```

My task is to visualise the relationship between "RENTALS" and "SEASON" based on "weatherCondition".

So far I managed to do the following:

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(data=bikes, mapping = aes(x = season, y = rentals)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = weatherCond)) +
  theme_bw()
```

The result is:

[image]

I assume that I'm heading in the right direction, but it's far from perfect.

1. It doesn't visualise the data perfectly.
2. I assume that providing more information regarding the correlation, the connection or the relationship between the variables would be beneficial.

How would you solve this problem?

Comment: There's not really a "right answer" here so this will probably get closed as opinion-based, but some ideas to think about: (a) geom_point is terrible here, lots of overplotting, can't distinguish colors well. Maybe try `geom_boxplot` or `geom_violin`. (b) Your `weatherCond` is being treated as continuous, but your data looks like it has 4 distinct values. But their meaning is not at all clear. Convert it to a `factor` variable with more descriptive names than `1 2 3 4`. (Ditto for `season`. We don't say "ooh, 4's here, it's cold out". Label your data meaningfully)

Comment: c) Small multiples are great. Maybe use `facet_wrap` to make small multiples plots by either season or weather condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would summarize the data by weather condition and season, given the weather conditions are not thousand different ones. Ideally both can be named, like "rain", "summer" etc. Either case, the following works.

**Data**

```
dat <- structure(list(rentals = c(12L, 6L, 21L, 4L, 5L, 19L, 13L, 10L, 
8L), season = c(1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), weatherCondition = c(4L, 
1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

```
res <- data.frame( aggregate( rentals ~ weatherCondition + season, dat, sum ))

# for numerical data
  weatherCondition season rentals
1                3      1      13
2                4      1      52
3                3      2       8
4                4      2      10
5                1      3       4
6                2      3       5
7                1      4       6

# for named conditions and seasons
  weatherCondition season rentals
1            rainy   fall       6
2            foggy spring       8
3            snowy spring      10
4            rainy summer       4
5            sunny summer       5
6            foggy winter      13
7            snowy winter      52
```

The plotting

```
barplot( res[,"rentals"], names=apply( res[,1:2], 1, function(x) paste0(x[1],"_",x[2]) ), las=3 )
```

[image: barplot]

Obviously, the labels don't make much sense here in my toy example.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. Good idea, I haven't thought about it. Yes, summarizing the data by weather condition and season would be possible, since the weather conditions are also only 4 (1 for perfect, 4 for bad). One thing: when I try to implement the first line of your code, I get the following error in RStudio: "Error in eval(m$data, parent.frame()) : object 'dat' not found". Do you have any idea what the issues could be? Thanks!

Comment: @Embargo96 I added the data I used. Simply use it for the example. In your real example simply swap in your data.

Comment: Thanks again, I am still very new to R and I thought that "dat" is some kind of function or a "tweak" for the plot. Then I saw that it was the data you used so I added my data and it worked. Do you think that some kind of (statistical) correlation or relationship between the variables could also be implemented here and if yes, how would you do it?

Comment: @Embargo96 You could do `cor(dat)` and plot the data with `heatmap( cor(dat) )` but I don't know how meaningful the result is.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you probably want grouped box plots. You can add colours or fills to this if necessary

```r
library(tidyverse)
bikes %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(season), y = rentals, group = factor(weatherCond))) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme_bw()
```